# What's the right way to include Android native binaries (.so files) in nugets for consumption in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget

We build nugets containing our app-specific native binaries.  We're pretty much just using nugets as a file transport mechanism though; we adjust the Xamarin projects to point to the the extracted libWhatever.so files in the packages/ directory, and mark them as EmbeddedNativeLibraries.

This works, but it feels much more like a hack than an actual solution.

So what is the right way to do this?  All the existing nuget documentation I've found assumes that native binaries are Windows dlls - certainly not useful in an Android context.

We need to be able include multiple architectures in the nugets, of course; armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86, etc.  Can't include Windows nastiness like powershell, either, since we mostly work on macs (Some threads I've seen in other places thought that fixing things up with powershell scripts embedded in the nuget might be the way to go).

Update:  there's a relevant discussion at https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/35517/is-it-possible-to-include-native-libraries-automatically-from-a-nuget-package

Answer (score 3):

Do it with a custom `.targets` in your Nuget's `build` directory that adds your shared library into your Android project's as `AndroidNativeLibrary` items. When you add the Nuget to your project, the target gets added to your `.csproj` and you are all set...

Example:

To include `libDNAGenetics.so` into an `Xamarin.Android` project's as `AndroidNativeLibrary` build items, create a `.targets` that includes:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <_DNAGeneticNugetNativePath Condition="'$(_DNAGeneticNugetNativePath)' == ''">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\native\</_DNAGeneticNugetNativePath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == 'MonoAndroid'">
    <AndroidNativeLibrary Include="$(_DNAGeneticNugetNativePath)android\armeabi-v7a\libDNAGenetics.so">
      <Link>$(_DNAGeneticNugetNativePath)android\armeabi-v7a\libDNAGenetics.so</Link>
    </AndroidNativeLibrary>
    <AndroidNativeLibrary Include="$(_DNAGeneticNugetNativePath)android\x86\libDNAGenetics.so">
      <Link>$(_DNAGeneticNugetNativePath)android\x86\libDNAGenetics.so</Link>
    </AndroidNativeLibrary>
    <AndroidNativeLibrary Include="$(_DNAGeneticNugetNativePath)android\arm64-v8a\libDNAGenetics.so">
      <Link>$(_DNAGeneticNugetNativePath)android\arm64-v8a\libDNAGenetics.so</Link>
    </AndroidNativeLibrary>
    <AndroidNativeLibrary Include="$(_DNAGeneticNugetNativePath)android\x86_64\libDNAGenetics.so">
      <Link>$(_DNAGeneticNugetNativePath)android\x86_64\libDNAGenetics.so</Link>
    </AndroidNativeLibrary>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is pointing me in the right direction.  Next thing is to figure out how to tell if the nuget is included in a library (meaning you have to replace all the AndroidNativeLibrary elements with EmbeddedNativeLibrary) or an app (in which case the xml you have does the right thing).

Comment: @JamesMoore Use a `Condition` in include/exclude a block within the `.targets` that checks if one of the `ProjectTypeGuids` includes `EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DC` (`Xamarin.Android`) and if `AndroidApplication` exists and set to true (Note: `AndroidApplication` is not included by default in library projects, but to be safe, check if it exists AND if it is set to true to determine if you are within an Android application vs. library)